# Using custom JQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following references to the javascripts libraries.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript-1.js"></script>
   <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#tabs-2').html("<p>jQuery add </p>");
       });
    </script>
```

In the html there is a div with id tabs-2. I am not able to control the html elements using JQuery scripts. The above simple in-line script is also not working.
I have also added a custom script file which has the jQuery function as stated in [this example](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/).

Any inputs on how to add use custom JQuery libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you call

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

you can no longer use `$`. You have to use `jQuery`, or, assign the return value from the `noConflict()` call to a variable and use that:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($) {
    // here you can use $ again
});
```

To keep your custom scripts compatible whether jQuery is in no-conflict mode or not, you could wrap it with an IIFE:

```
(function($) {
    // your code that uses '$'
})(jQuery);
```

See: [jQuery.noConflict() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm!
I had used the same way like
     (function () {
      })(jQuery.noConflict());

I was not sending the $ parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

means that jQUery runs in no conflict mode.  This means that `$` is not aliased to the jQuery object and you have to use `jQuery`isntead of `$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `noConflict()` function

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

[JQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation!